# Is Weibull distribution a exponential family?

Tags: weibull-distribution, exponential-family

I'm wondering is Weibull distribution a exponential family?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is NO. The logarithm of the weibull density is given by
$$
   \log f(x) = \log(k/\lambda) + (k-1)\log(x/\lambda)  - (x/\lambda)^k
$$
where $x>0$, $k>0$ (shape parameter), $\lambda>0$ (scale parameter).  The problem is the last term. IF $k$ were known (prespecified), this would be a one-parameter exponential family. So one could say (maybe) that the two-parameter weibull family is an (infinite) union of one-parameter exponential families, but if that is of any help I do not know.

To see this, the general form of the multi-parameter exponential family is 
$$
   f(x;\theta) = h(x) \exp( \sum_1^s \eta_i(\theta) T_i(x) - A(\theta)
$$
we can se that the parameter function $\eta_i(\theta)$ and the data function $T_i(x)$ always combines multiplicatively, which do not happen for the last term in the weibull formula above.

Comment: @Neil G: Wikipedia agrees with me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family  (its a long article, search for weibull)

Answer (score 4):

The two parameter Weibull distribution (with $k$ and $\lambda$ as described on wikipedia) is not an exponential family.  However, if you fix $k$ to anything, then it is an exponential family having sufficient statistics $x^k$ on support $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Here is a similar question:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87501/show-that-weibull-distribution-can-be-transformed-to-exponential-family

Comment: OK, planetmath agree with you: http://planetmath.org/exponentialfamily  but they don't argue ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I updated my answer.  I only remember having read that it was an exponential family, but I never tried to put it into canonical form.  You're right: unless you fix $k$, it's not an exponential family.